# Conversion functions from string to date time in Bigquery/SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a string value as `"5/10/2019 4:21:20 PM"` in one column, I have to convert into valid datetime to `"2019-10-05T16:21:20"`.

We are using big query database.

I have tried with Date and timestamp functions but its throwing error as Invalid timestamp: `"5/10/2019 4:21:20 PM"`

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y %r', '5/10/2019 4:21:20 PM')
```

with result

```
2019-10-05T16:21:20
```

You can read more about [Supported format elements for DATETIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#supported-format-elements-for-datetime)